# Ordering and counting dimension keys and sort by another key

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

Assuming a table like this:

| xid | yid | otherStuff |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 100 | Three |
| 1000 | 101 | Car |
| 1001 | 100 | Flower |
| 1001 | 100 | Flower |
| 1000 | 100 | Three |
| 1002 | 101 | Bus |
| 1003 | 101 | Train |
| 1002 | 100 | Bee |
| 1001 | 102 | Iron |
| 1002 | 102 | Gold |
| 1003 | 102 | Silver |
| 1001 | 102 | Iron |
| 1000 | 100 | Three |

I would like to return the xids ordered by count(*). The order should be first the xids where yid = 100 then where yid != 100

So the result should be

```
1000 (because yid = 100, count(*) = 3 )
1001 (because yid = 100, count(*) = 2 )
1002 (because yid = 100, count(*) = 1 )
1003 (because yid != 100, count(*) = 2 (even yid !=yid)
```

Every ordered xid should only appear one single time. My approach does not return the single ids it repeats the xids

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT [xid], 
  [yid],
  count(1) as cnt 
FROM [fbfact].[Journal]
where [yid] = 1000 
group by [xid],[yid]
UNION
SELECT [xid],
   [yid],
   count(1) as cnt
FROM [fbfact].[Journal]
where [yid] != 1000
group by [xid],[yid] ) as x
```

I can't get my head around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option, you could use a conditional count function as the following:

```
select xid
from table_name
group by xid
order by count(case when yid = 100 then 1 end) desc,
         count(case when yid <> 100 then 1 end) desc
```

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/RRkmzj4-)

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
select xid
from (
  select xid, count(*) as cnt,
    max(case when yid = 100 then 1 else 0 end) as has_100
  from [fbfact].[Journal]
  group by xid
) x
order by has_100 desc, cnt desc
```

Answer (score 1):

You could order by a windowed count,

```
select xid
from (
  select distinct xid, Count(case when yid = 100 then xid end) over(partition by xid) o
  from fbfact.Journal
)x
order by o desc;
```